# Login to Microsoft Live using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to automate login to Microsoft login.live.com live using selenium. The source code of the email field is below.
I tried using xpath but I am getting this error
Could you help me to send keys to that field and then other keys in password field and connect.
Thank you.

What I tried for the Email box

```
    driver.get('https://login.live.com/login.srf')
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='form-control ltr_override input ext-input text-box ext-text-box' and @name='loginfmt']")
```

Error: *Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@class='form-control ltr_override input ext-input text-box ext-text-box' and @name='loginf*

Email field

```
    <input type="email" name="loginfmt" id="i0116" maxlength="113" lang="en" class="form-control ltr_override input ext-input text-box ext-text-box" aria-required="true" data-bind="
                    externalCss: {
                        'input': true,
                        'text-box': true,
                        'has-error': usernameTextbox.error },
                    ariaLabel: tenantBranding.UserIdLabel || str['CT_PWD_STR_Username_AriaLabel'],
                    ariaDescribedBy: 'loginHeader' + (pageDescription &amp;&amp; !svr.bZ ? ' loginDescription' : ''),
                    textInput: usernameTextbox.value,
                    hasFocusEx: usernameTextbox.focused,
                    placeholder: $placeholderText" aria-label="Saisissez votre contact e-mail, téléphone ou Skype." aria-describedby="loginHeader" placeholder="E-mail, téléphone ou Skype">
```

Password field

```
<input name="passwd" type="password" id="i0118" autocomplete="off" data-bind="moveOffScreen, textInput: passwordBrowserPrefill" class="moveOffScreen" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: I believe you can't locate on compound class names like that.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't locate on compound class names like that. Since you have the name attribute, try locating on that:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='loginfmt']")
```

and likewise for password:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='passwd']")
```